# Is there a way to collapse all C# code blocks, ignoring #region definitions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

There is a plenty of documentation on various VS hot-keys for managing the code-collapse functionality of the editor.  However, I've not found a single feature (either by hotkey or buried in a menu) that will let me collapse all methods AND ignore all `#region` sections, leaving them uncollapsed.

In my case, I manage numerous older code files that sometimes consist of over 10k-locs.  I didn't write this code and most of the methods are organized into C# preprocessor regions.  When I execute a "Collapse All" I see a list of 20-30+ regions of code, collapsed along with their methods and properties defined within them.  If I want to scan all of the document methods and properties, I need to expand every single region.  This gets tedious, especially when you have to jump from file-to-file, each just as big as the last.

Has anyone else experienced this <strike>need</strike> desire and found a way to collapse all block-based code blocks, while expanding all `region` blocks?  If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Possibly just do collapse all in VS and then *Expand all regions* from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f702b0aa-56c3-4ad8-91b4-5e653e0ba1c3

Comment: @ta.speot.is This could work.  I assume that since this is an external VS tool, then this isn't integrated into any version of VS?

Comment: Ha ha ha, a related post from Fr. Atwood circa 2008: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc07ec7e-abfa-425f-bb65-2411a260b926

Or

if you are using VS2012, the option is typically found in the Edit menu under Outlining->Collapse All Definitions.

Comment: This is not the answer.  Yes, a VS extension may work but Collapse all to definitions is only half of the solution, of which I am well aware of.  Collapsing to definitions also collapses all regions.  I still need to mindlessly expand 20-30 regions in large code files, when I'd prefer to just use a scroll wheel to skim method names (See Atwood's post in my comment under the question.)